# Laravel 5.0 eloquent not adding timestamps for created_at and updted_at

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am having this code in my controller

```
foreach($blogTags as $blogTagsData) 
      {
            $data[] = array(
          'blog_id' => $postBlog->id,
          'user_id' => '1',  
          'tag_id' => $blogTagsData[0]);

      }
      BlogTag::insert($data);
```

Where $blogTags will have 1,2,3 like that.

But when i do the `insert` it is not inserting the timestamps in the created_at field and updated_at field..

Even i have this inside my model

`public $timestamps = true;`

What is the mistake i am doing,,,

Is only doing the following way only option ?

```
$data['created_at']= \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
$data['updated_at']= \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
```

Or is there any better way to include the laravel default timestamp insertion ..

Comment: Can you `print_r($blogTags)`?

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)`

Comment: You want to only get the index 0 for that?

Comment: Nope, i wanted to add some additional values which laravel adds itself in the eloquent way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
foreach ($blogTags as $blogTagsData) {
    BlogTag::create([
        'blog_id' => $postBlog->id,
        'user_id' => '1',
        'tag_id' => $blogTagsData[0]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Ah.. I am getting this error `Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::save() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context`

Comment: While this works, when adding a lot of fields the  Model::create() is slower to insert as it makes various INSERT INTO blogtags (column,column, column) VALUES ($val,$val,$val); while the post author was doing it the better way which leads to INSERT INTO (column, column, column) VALUES ($val, $val, $val),  ($val, $val, $val), ... .  This post explains better http://bensmith.io/speeding-up-laravel-seeders